# Having to set reset flag with truffle migrate

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration

I am having a weird issue where my migrations are not being deployed when I run `truffle migrate --network development`.  But when I run `truffle migrate --network development --reset`, the contracts are being deployed correctly.  Does anybody know what the cause to this could be?

I am on truffle version 4.0.1 and solidity version 0.4.18.

This is an example of the console messages I am seeing.  In this picture I just added the staging network to my truffle.js before running these migrate commands. (The authentication error is expected)

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. I even tested it with the Metacoin.sol contract which is generated by truffle init.

Answer (score 3):

Have you previously migrated the contracts?  If you ran a previous migration and didn't change any of the contracts/migration details, truffle migrate will not do anything.  `--reset` forces it to run the entire migration from the beginning.

https://truffle.readthedocs.io/en/beta/getting_started/migrations/

> $ truffle migrate
>
> This will run all migrations located within your project's migrations directory. If your migrations were previously run successfully, truffle migrate will start execution from the last migration that was ran, running only newly created migrations. If no new migrations exists, truffle migrate won't perform any action at all. You can use the --reset option to run all your migrations from the beginning.